# Datamatrix not generated on Mac

Tags: xetex, miktex, pstricks, pst-barcode

When I compile the following file on my Mac, the datamatrix is not generated. When I compile the same file on a Linux server, the datamatrix is shown.

Do you have any idea how this datamatrix can be generated on Mac and Linux?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}


This is exemple of Data Matrix code.\vspace{10mm}
\begin{center}
\psbarcode{This is an empty code}{parse,format=square: version=18x18}{datamatrix}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with xelatex.

These are the file versions used:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pst-barcode.sty    2016/04/22 package wrapper for pst-barcode.tex (hv)
pstricks.sty    2018/01/06 v0.67 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2018/08/23 v2.86 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2018/08/23 v2.86 `PST-fp' (hv)
pst-barcode.tex    2017/08/22 v0.18 `PST-barcode' (hv)
marginnote.sty    2018/08/09 v1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
 ***********
```

Comment: Compare the log-files to find out what is different.

Answer (score 1):

put `\listfiles` as first line into your document and compare the 
file list at the end of your log file with this one (I have no problem with
your example and an up-to-date MacTeX).

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pst-barcode.sty    2016/04/22 package wrapper for pst-barcode.tex (hv)
pstricks.sty    2018/02/08 v0.68 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2018/12/16 v2.89 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2018/12/16 v2.89 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro    2018/11/14 v. 1.29, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro    2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro    2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-barcode.tex    2017/08/22 v0.18 `PST-barcode' (hv)
marginnote.sty    2018/08/09 v1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
pst-barcode.pro    2017/04/04 PostScript prologue file (hv)
 ***********
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated all packages by using MiKTeX console, but it is still not working. Can you see what might be missing based on the listed files? pst-barcode.pro is obviously missing. Would this be the reason?

Comment: run in a terminal:  `kpsewhich pst-barcode.pro` If you do not get an output then the file is missing.

Comment: No problem with MiKTeX. The pro file is not listed because miktex has an old style file, which doesn’t matter here

Comment: Best thing would be to get rid of MiKTeX ?  Or do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Create a test directory and save the doc, pst-barcode.tex and .pro file in this directory. Does it work?